# Proving that an equation holds when we divide a square in triangles

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Consider the following square of side $1$ divided into right triangles:

[image]

Prove that the following equation holds:

[image]

I tried first using the Pythagorean theorem, getting 7 equations, one for each triangle, and after combining the equations, I got the following:

$$BI^2=-DE^2-FH^2-HI^2+2(GI)(EG)+2(GI)(CE)+2(EG)(CE).$$

Also, the sum of the areas of the triangles is $1$, and the area of each triangle is the product of the legs divided by $2$, but I know know if this can help (combined with the equation I got), or am I going on the wrong way?

Comment: Are given that AB=BC=DC=x + HF + FD.  And you have 7 pythagorean equations.  By substitution you should be able to get the conclusion.  I wouldn't worry about area. so much as the above identity.

Comment: Notice that all the triangles are similar.

Comment: Yeah, I already substitued AB=BC=DC=1=x+HF+HD to get the equation I gave.

Comment: I wouldn't use Pythagoras but orthogonal projection instead. Assume we have $x$. Then we have the point $(x,1)$. With that compute the orthogonal projection, $I$, of $(1,0)$ to the line $BH$. With that the orthogonal projection, $E$, of $D$ to $CI$. Then the orthogonal projection from $E$ to $AD$. ... Eventually the orthogonal projection of $G$ to $AD$. Finally, impose that the coordinates of the resulting $H$ are $(x,1)$. Tat gives you directly the equation for $x$.

Comment: By using Pythagoras it is less clear if the equations considered are all the ones necessary. Maybe they are algebraically dependent. It is harder to tell until you get the final solution. In addition there are more variables to eliminate in order to end with an equation only for $x$.

Comment: As the triangles are similar, using the pyth theor will yield some polynomial.  It may be tedious and messy (I was not willing to finish it) but it will get you there.  If the OP is comfortable with orthogonal projection and it's easier, by all means use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First prove all the triangles are similar.  This is easy as all angles are right or supplementary or congruent.

So

$AH = x$.  $AB = 1$.  $\frac {BI}{x} = \frac 1{\sqrt{1 + x^2}}; BI = \frac x{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$. $HI = \sqrt{ 1+x^2}- \frac x{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$.

$\frac {IG}{HI} = \frac x1; IG = x(\sqrt{ 1-x^2}- \frac x{\sqrt{1-x^2}});\frac {IG}{HG} = \frac {IB}1$. etc.

And so on.

By the end you will get $IG + GE +EC = \frac 1{\sqrt{1 - x^2}}$ and that $EC^2 + ED^2 = 1$.

One assumes putting all in terms of $x$ will yield the equation given.

====

Okay, let's put this together.

What is the scaling factor of each triangle:

$\triangle AHB$ is our basic the triangle with factor of $1$.  It's dimensions are:  $AH = x; AB= 1; BH = \sqrt{1 + x^2}$

$\triangle BIC$ is proportional ot $\triangle AHB$ and and it's sides are in proportion of $\frac {BI}{AH} = \frac {BC}{BH}=\frac {IC}{AB} = \frac{BI}x = \frac {1}{\sqrt {1 + x^2}} =  {IC}$.  So scaling factor is $\frac 1{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$.  (Note: every scaling factor is the length of the long leg.)

$\triangle HIC$ has scaling factor of $HI= BH - BI = \sqrt{1+x^2} - AH*\frac 1{\sqrt{1+x^2}}= \frac {\sqrt{1+x^2}\sqrt{1+x^2}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} - \frac x{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=\frac {1 - x  +x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$

$\triangle HFG$ has scaling factor $HG =\frac {1 - x  +x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}*HB = 1-x + x^2$.

$\triangle FGE$ has scaling factor $FG = (1-x + x^2)HB = (1-x+x^2)\sqrt{1+x^2}$.

$\triangle FDE$ has scaling factor $FE = (1-x+x^2)\sqrt{1+x^2}*HB = (1-x+x^2)(1+x^2)$.

Finally $\triangle DEC$ has scaling factor $DE = (1-x+x^2)(1+x^2)*HB =  (1-x+x^2)(1+x^2)\sqrt{1 + x^2}$.

So $1 = DC = HB* (1-x+x^2)(1+x^2)\sqrt{1 + x^2} = (1-x+x^2)(1+x^2)^2$.

So $(1+x^2)^2(1-x+x^2) - 1 = 0$

$(1 + 2x^2 + x^4)(1 - x +x^2)-1 = (1 + 2x^2 + x^4)- (x + 2x^3 + x^5)+(x^2 + 2x^4 + x^6)-1= x^6-x^5 +3x^4 -2x^3 +3x^2 - x + 1-1 =x(x^5-x^4 +3x^3 -2x^2 +3x - 1)= 0$

So $x^5-x^4 +3x^3 -2x^2 +3x - 1=0$.

Comment: Wouldn't it be $\sqrt{1+x^2}$ since it's the hypotenuse?

Comment: Isn't that what I wrote.... Oh, googly-moogly.... yes, that is correct.

Comment: and I don't get why $IG=IB$

Comment: It doesn't.  I'm not sure why I wrote that. IG = x*HI.  And IG/HG = IB.

Comment: I did everything and didn't arrive to the equation needed. I don't accept this as an answer since the person who answered is not even sure of what he wrote and if this works.

Comment: It works.  You didn't follow it through completely (which turned out not to be as tedious as I thought it'd be).

Comment: BI got the same values for $IC$, $HI$, $HG$, and $FG$ as you do. But for $FE$ I wrote $\frac{FD}{FE}=\frac{HB}{AB}$, making $FE=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$, which is true but leads to $$DC=DE\times HB=\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$ which is not helpful.  But equating my value for $FE$ with yours:$$\frac{1}{1+x^2}=(1-x+x^2)(1+x^2)$$finally gives the desired result$$x(x^5-x^4+3x^3-2x^2+3x-1)=0$$I would guess that $x$ here cannot be constructed by Euclidean methods, I.e. that the figure cannot be drawn with ruler and compass?

Comment: I haven't really thought about whether $x$ is constructable.  But as it is a solution to a quintic rather than a power of $2$ polynomial it probably isn't.  Unless the quintic can be reduced to power of $2$ polynomials.  Which I'm pretty sure it cant.  The rational roots th says if there are any rational roots they are $\pm 1$ and those don't work so no, it isn't constructable.  Interesting that is is one real root but if there are other real roots, I don't know how to determine which it is.